# reverse() throws AttributeError on call

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to reverse a named url called `blog-home` but no matter what I try it always throws an `AttributeError` with the description `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rindex'`.

I've tried `reverse("blog-home")`, `reverse("blogengine:blog-home")` and even `reverse("admin:index")` and `reverse(resolve("/admin/"))` just to test if my code was the problem.

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 368, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 241, in _get_app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 208, in _populate
    for name in pattern.reverse_dict:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 229, in _get_reverse_dict
    self._populate()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 220, in _populate
    lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 169, in _get_callback
    mod_name, func_name = get_mod_func(self._callback_str)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django-1.3-py2.7.egg\django\core\urlresolvers.py", line 113, in get_mod_func
    dot = callback.rindex('.')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rindex'
```

I'm really not sure about why this happens, especially as I've used `reverse` successfully on other projects with the same version of Python and Django and I haven't found anything about this error anywhere else so far.

My urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

from . import views
from .models import Post, Tag

from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(queryset=Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')), name="blog-home"),
    url(r'^yadda/$', None)
)
```

Which is imported by this urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

from django.contrib.sitemaps import FlatPageSitemap

class FlatPageSitemap(FlatPageSitemap):
    changefreq = "daily"

sitemaps = {
    'flatpages': FlatPageSitemap,
}

import django.contrib.sitemaps.views
from . import blogengine

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(blogengine.urls)),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml', django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
    url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

I was originally intending to use it from the Django templating system with the url tag (`{% url blog-home %}`).

Comment: could you show us your urls.py containing `blog-home` and the code you are using where the `reverse` method is called. Apparently, something is null.

Comment: I'm just invoking `reverse` from a `manage.py shell` interactive shell for now, while debugging.

Comment: The point @cx42net is making is that there are many things that affect `reverse`. It could be choking on something in urls.py or in one of your views. There's nothing wrong with how you're calling `reverse`, so the error must be somewhere else in your code. We need more context to help you further.

Comment: Okay, @chrisdpratt, but I'm not really sure about what kind of context it is that you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't do that:

```
url(r'^yadda/$', None)
```

If you specify an URL in the conf, it must be bound to something. If you don't want to bind it, don't specify it.

Comment: You're right. Note to self: don't just place placeholder urlconfigs next time.