# Django admin - 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rindex'

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm working through the Django 1.0 Website Development book. At Chapter 8, I can't get the admin application to work. Here is the traceback I'm getting.

```
Environment:

Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/

Django Version: 1.3
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_bookmarks.bookmarks',
 'debug_toolbar',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.admindocs']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfResponseMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  252.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  158.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in _get_callback
  169.             mod_name, func_name = get_mod_func(self._callback_str)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_mod_func
  113.         dot = callback.rindex('.')

Exception Type: AttributeError at /admin/
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'rindex'
```

Here is my INSTALLED_APPS section from the settings.py file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django_bookmarks.bookmarks',
    'debug_toolbar',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Here is my admin.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from bookmarks.models import *


class LinkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  pass


class TagAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  pass


class BookmarkAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
  list_display = ('title', 'link', 'user')
  list_filter = ('user',)
  ordering = ('title',)
  search_fields = ('title',)


admin.site.register(Link, LinkAdmin)
admin.site.register(Tag, TagAdmin)
admin.site.register(Bookmark, BookmarkAdmin)
```

Here is my urls.py file:

```
import os
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic.simple import direct_to_template
from bookmarks.views import *
from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()


site_media = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'site_media')


urlpatterns = patterns('',
    # Admin interface
    (r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root_path),

    # Browsing
    (r'^$', main_page),
    (r'^popular/$', popular_page),
    (r'^user/(\w+)/$', user_page),
    (r'^tag/([^\s]+)/$', tag_page),
    (r'^tag/$', tag_cloud_page),
    (r'^search/$', search_page),
    (r'^bookmark/(\d+)/$', bookmark_page),

    # Session management
    (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login'),
    (r'^logout/$', logout_page),
    (r'^register/$', register_page),
    (r'^register/success/$', direct_to_template,
    {'template': 'registration/register_success.html'}),

    # Account management
    (r'^save/$', bookmark_save_page),
    (r'^vote/$', bookmark_vote_page),

    # Site media
    (r'^site_media/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': site_media}),

    # Ajax
    (r'^ajax/tag/autocomplete/$', ajax_tag_autocomplete),

    # Comments
    (r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),

)
```

I've tried copying the urls.py file from the book's source code = NADA. I've read various other forum posts on attribute errors, but can't seem to find a scenario that matches mine. Your ideas & suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: post the code for your urls.py and admin.py if you have one. Also, can you post the INSTALLED_APPS part of your settings.py?

Comment: Sure thing...added the code you requested.

Comment: Hmmm, what version of Django are you using. That book you mentioned was published in 2009 and might be using an out of date version of Django. Have a look at the docs from the Djagno website: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/#activate-the-admin-site

Comment: Using Django 1.3, which is supposed to be backward compatible with 1.x versions, as I understand. Please see my edited post for what happens if I change urls.py from `(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root_path)` to `(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.urls)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's:

```
(r'^admin/(.*)', admin.site.root_path),
```

that's causing the error, because `admin.site.root_path` is equal to `None`.

The correct value is:

```
(r'^admin/(.*)', include(admin.site.urls)),
```

Comment: Ok, thanks pastylegs and manji for `(r'^admin/(.*)', include(admin.site.urls))` Changing to that URL gave me a new recursion error that I was able to troubleshoot and correct. I'm now able to login to my admin interface.

Answer (score 9):

This also happened to me when I forgot to return decorator in one of my decorators:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseForbidden

def admin_required(func):
    def decorator(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        if not request.user.is_superuser():
            return HttpResponseForbidden()

        return func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    return decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

It's expecting the `callback` variable to be a string, but it's getting `None` instead.  First thing I'd check is that you've got `debug_toolbar` in the right place and referenced correctly.  Remove `debug_toolbar` and see if the error goes away.

Answer (score 0):

Check this question:

[reverse() throws AttributeError on call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268512/reverse-throws-attributeerror-on-call)

Maybe some of the functions you pass as second item in the urls tuples evaluates to None.